# Can't Revert Minicom Configuration

Tags: raspbian

## w/ Raspberry Pi - Bullseye, Full, 64bit

I have been using /dev/ttyUSB2 every day for the last month.Today I changed it to /dev/ttyUSB3 and now can't get it to change back.

minicom

- works and loads config file

sudo minicom

- "minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB3: No such file or directory" because it's still getting the modem setting from somewhere else entirely.

sudo minicom -s

- saves file properly but the file isn't used on startup

sudo minicom configuration /etc/minicom/minirc.dfl

- "minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory"

/dev/ttyUSB3 persists even after using: sudo apt-get purge --autoremove minicom

/etc/minicom/minirc.dfl :

# Machine-generated file - use "minicom -s" to change parameters.

pu port             /dev/ttyUSB2

Answer (score 0):

Use `minicom -s` to set the serial port.

`minicom -s` will set the current user's configuration.

`sudo minicom -s` will set root's configuration.

Comment: "minicom -s" works, but "sudo minicom" is broken. It doesn't save to its own root config anymore, but still loads the one with the incorrect port. Saving worked until the non-existing port was saved, but now saving doesn't work. Again - "minicom -s" does work.